# How do I create dynamically text in a movie clip using as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, text, dynamic, movieclip, gravity

I would like to create text animated like a comet. I would like to create a gravity effect, accelerate the movie clip on vector, set a starting position on stage and load the text from a xml file.

Answer (score 5):

> How do I create dynamically text in a
>   movie clip using as3?

you create a TextField like any other DisplayObject and add it to the parent you want.

e.g.

```
var myText:TextField = new TextField();
myClip.addChild(myText);
myText.text = 'Hello!';
```

I don't think I fully understand your question. From what I understand you should:

1. load the xml so you would have the
   text beforehand( you wouldn't need
   to wait for the xml to load while
   you're playing the animation
2. add your clips and textield
3. animate

One thing to be aware if you're animating text: dynamic text looks better animated when you've got the font embedded, also if you plan to animate rotation or alpha you will need to embed fonts, otherwise you won't be able to animate those properties.

Good luck!